# R shiny uncheck checkboxGroup with actionbutton

Tags: r, button, checkbox, shiny

I have checkboxGroup with selected items, and actionButton. I need on actionButton click uncheck checkBoxGroup.

```
          wellPanel(
             checkboxGroupInput(datename, "Select dates:", some_dates,
                                selected = outlier_dates_to_select),
             actionButton("buttonname", "Uncheck all")
        )
```

Any suggestions, how I can manage that?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `actionButton` like this for example :

In ui.R :

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(title=""),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("Test1", "Test1", choices=c("1","2","3"), selected="1"),
    checkboxGroupInput("Test2", "Test2", choices=c("1","2","3"), selected="2"),
    actionButton("Uncheck", label="Uncheck")
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

And in server.R :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
   if (input$Uncheck > 0) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId="Test1", choices=c("1","2","3"), selected=NULL)
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId="Test2", choices=c("1","2","3"), selected=NULL)
   }
 })
})
```

You have to repeat choices in `updateCheckboxGroupInput` to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to do that with checkboxGroupInput, not with checkboxInput. Because I have to dynamically change checkboxgroupinput list and selected items list.

Comment: Sorry i misread your question, i edited my answer, does it better?

Comment: Thank you a lot! And for first answer too! Owing to your idea on updateCheckbox, I found function updateCheckboxGroupInput.