# Shiny dynamic UI with clear checkbox button

Tags: r, shiny, dynamic-ui

How can we add a "Clear" button to reset check box values to NULL in an app with a dynamic UI?

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Group" = c("Group A", "Group B", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B"),
  "Name" = c("Bob", "Paul", "Peter", "Emma", "John"),
  "Value" = seq(1,10, length.out=5),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df
    Group  Name Value
1 Group A   Bob  1.00
2 Group B  Paul  3.25
3 Group A Peter  5.50
4 Group A  Emma  7.75
5 Group B  John 10.00
```

I create one tab per `Group` and a checkbox of `Name` values:

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput('mytabs')
  )
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Tabs_titles = unique(df$Group)

  # Dynamic UI
  output$mytabs <- renderUI({
    myTabs <- lapply(Tabs_titles,
                     function(x){
                       tabPanel(title = x,
                                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = paste0("checkboxID_", x),
                                                   label = "My Checkbox",
                                                   choices = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name),
                                                   selected = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name)
                                ),
                                checkboxInput(paste0("clear_", x), "Clear"),
                                tableOutput(paste0("my_Table_", x))
                       )
                     }
    )

    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)

  })


  observe(
    lapply(Tabs_titles,
           function(x){
             checked_names <- reactive({input[[paste0("checkboxID_", x)]]})

             # Table
             output[[paste0("my_Table_", x)]] <-renderTable({
               df %>%
               subset(Group == x & Name %in% checked_names())
             })

             # Clear button here
             observe({
               if(req(input[[paste0("clear_", x)]]) == TRUE){
                 updateCheckboxGroupInput(
                  session,
                  paste0("checkboxID_", x),
                  choices = df %>% subset(Group == x) %>% pull(Name),
                  selected = NULL
                )
               }
             })
           }
    )
  )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when checked, the `Clear` box does not trigger anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using modules?

Comment: That's right, modules may be more convenient for this case.

Answer (score 0):

From the online help for `updateCheckboxGroupInput`: Any arguments with NULL values will be ignored; *they will not result in any changes to the input object on the client*.  [My emphasis.]

You have `selected = NULL`.  Perhaps `selected=c()` will give you what you want?

**Edit**
Contradicting what I wrote above, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904869/r-shiny-uncheck-checkboxgroup-with-actionbutton) suggests a different solution.

**Edit 2**
This proof-of-concept example works as expected.  So it's likely you have a second issue in your code which is interacting with the working solution.  As I may have mentioned before: using modules would make your life easier: each module would be responsible for clearing its own `checkboxGroupInput`, so indexing would not be a concern.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Clear checkboxGroup Test"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("clear", "Clear")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("group", "The Beatles", choices=c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"))
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "group", choices=c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"), selected=NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Still nothing happening with `selected=c()` or without mentioning `selected` at all (equivalent to `selected = NULL` as you mentioned).

Comment: Using an `actionButton` with `if(req(input[[paste0("clear_", x)]]) > 0){...}` does not trigger anything neither.

Comment: The actionButton does trigger.  However, updateCheckboxGroupInput does not update anything.

Comment: The toy example also works with `selected=c()` in place of `selected=NULL`.  I'm confident there's more than one issue in the OP's code.

Comment: I am able to make the button work as well for static UI. I agree, that modules would help with indexing.

Comment: @JohannesNE, Maybe the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` is not updating anything due to the if statement? I find it weird to be forced to use `req()` for calling the `input$button`. Maybe it is related